# Expanded CSS on Sass Compile in Node

Tags: node.js, node-sass

I am using node-sass to compile my sass.  I would like the output to be expanded.  Currently, my `package.json` script looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
"compile:sass": "node-sass --watch sass/main.scss css/style.css --style expanded"
}
```

However, my output isn't expanding:

```
nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  padding: 2em; }
  nav a {
    list-style-type: none; }
```

Is there a different way to write the script so it will properly expand?

Answer (score 0):

Use `--output-style=expanded` for node-sass:

```
"scripts": {
    "compile:sass": "node-sass --watch sass/main.scss css/style.css --output-style=expanded"
}
```

as per OP @megler's own prior edit to the question.